# creating a website using angularjs in front end and in back end using falcon

Tags: angularjs, falconframework

Can anybody just tell me is it possible to achieve? I am trying to create a website using angularjs- front end and falcon- back end. So, how could i integrate them so that my form data get posted to back end?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?dcr=0&source=hp&ei=ih6qWsOoHYn1vgS5qRo&q=angularjs+falcon+&oq=angularjs+falcon+&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1.6081.13017.0.13305.20.16.0.0.0.0.535.2448.0j2j3j1j1j1.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..12.8.2446.0..0j35i39k1j0i67k1j0i20i263k1j0i22i10i30k1.0.QWbeeg6izb8) is helps to this type of question

Comment: Use Node js instead of the falcon-back end and also brush up using angularjs documentation and nodejs documentation

Comment: actually i am using REST API calls and i did some R&D and found that falcon is very powerful for that. Is there any other way rather than now starting with nodejs. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It is possible to achieve. I have Falcon and Angular 5 running in production and deployed on AWS Beanstalk and they've been playing very nicely together.

It's hard to answer your question without knowing what you have already tried. If you have not started yet, I suggest you start with the simplest setup for both Falcon and Angular (I'm going to assume Angular 5). 
This is a very rough plan to get started:

1) Install Falcon library; copy [the example API from Falcon](https://falconframework.org/) and run the server.

2) Download the example APP from [Angular Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)

3) Edit [HeroService](https://stackblitz.com/angular/nlvrooxxdvy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero.service.ts) to get data from your API server.

If everything goes well, you should be able to get here within an hour or so. Once you see Angular calling your Falcon backend and fetch data you know you've got a basis to start from. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I will try with this :)

Comment: @PratibhaRai You are welcome. If this answers your question, please accept the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Use Node js instead of the falcon-back end and also brush up using angularjs documentation and nodejs documentation